# wpf Updating UI dynamically without freezing UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, mvvm

The code is generating selected directory visual tree. but as it may takes a long time I need to do it in a background thread and don't freez the UI.
Problem is as I'm creating UI elements it doesn't allow me to do it outside the main UI thread.

```
        BackgroundWorker doMacBk;
        doMacBk = new BackgroundWorker();
        doMacBk.DoWork += (o, arg) =>
        {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    //Making UI elements
                }));
            }
        };
```

How should I do this without freezing UI?

Comment: Use the power of WPF with Bindings, DataTemplates and Virtualization

Comment: Do not create UI elements in code behind. For background processing, take a look at [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh191443(v=vs.120)).

Comment: There's very little point in using a background worker and then immediately invoking on the dispatcher. The point of a background worker is to do heavy non-UI work.

Answer (score -2):

You can do everything in your background thread and finally just add your controls to UI tree using Application.Current.Dispatcher.